# kendo treeView change node text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

Is it possible to dinamically change text in the kendo treeView?

```
var dataSource = treeView.dataSource;
var dataItem = dataSource.get(parseInt($('#inputIdOrgJed' + '@guid').val(), 10));
var node = treeView.findByUid(dataItem.uid);
treeView.select(node);
treeView.text(node, "ChangedText");
```

On ajax Update a node text should directly change. read action closes the tree so I cant use it, unless there is a way to avoid this.

Comment: [check this](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/treeview/changing-text-of-a-node.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

dataItem() is an observable array, so using .set() should cause the renderers to update the display automatically.

Presuming the data item text field is named 'text'.

```
treeview.dataItem(node).set('text', "New node text");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var selectedNode = treeview.select();
 var item = treeview.dataItem(selectedNode);  
 item.set("text", "Changed Text");
```

the point is the first parameter of `item.set("text"`  that should be the `dataTextField` defined in`kendoTreeView` configuration.